# How to make my main WinForm update when another closes?

Tags: c#, winforms

There's a duplicate post but the question was not answered. 
My question is if a new form is created within a main form

```
var editor = new Edit(itemList, itemListBox);
editor.Show();
```

and the type of data you edit is:

```
Dictionary<int, Item>
```

Item is below:

```
public class Item
{
    public string @Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Item(string @url, string name, double price)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

How can i add a handler for when editor is closed so it can update the ListBox in the main windows form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add an eventhandler for the [`Form.Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx) event

```
var editor = new Edit(itemList, itemListBox);
editor.Closed += OnEditorClosed(); // your eventhandler here
editor.Show();
```

or simply create modal dialog by using [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) instead of `Show`

```
var editor = new Edit(itemList, itemListBox);
editor.ShowDialog(); // execution will stop here until editor is closed
```

Comment: Thanks! i'll set this as the answer in 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Form has event handlers FormClosing and FormClosed. I think it'll be better to use the first one, since in the second the form's data may be alrready disposed. So:

```
editor.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(editor_FormClosing);

private void editor_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Edit editor = (Edit)sender;
    // update data on main form here
}
```